# How can I read network device names into a script from an external CSV or text file?

Tags: file-io, tcl, expect

I've done the following sample script in Exepct language to backup my network devices configuration (cisco devices)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# ---------------- configuration ---------------- #

set device 192.168.244.20   
set user go00080         
set pass password        
set tftp 192.168.244.243              
set timeout 60

# -------------- core -------------- #
spawn telnet $device
expect "Username:"
send "$user\n"
expect "Password:"
send "$pass\n"
send "copy running-config tftp://192.168.244.243\r"
expect "Address or name of remote host"
send "\r"
expect "Destination filename "
send "\r"
expect "secs"
send "exit\r"
close
exit 0
```

Now, I want that my script load $device from a csv or more simple from a txt file; I mean, suppose that my txt file contains all cisco ip address in the following way:

```
192.168.244.20
192.158.244.21
...
192.168.244.245
```

I want that script once loaded txt file, load one ip address each time, assign that ip address to $device variable and then make command "copy running-config..." 
How can I do? Anyone can help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# -------------- core -------------- #
set file_handle [open text.txt r]
while {[gets $file_handle device] != -1} {
    spawn telnet $device
    #... same as above
    send "exit\r"
    expect eof
}
close $file_handle
```

For help on specific commands, see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/contents.htm

Comment: Could use the csv package from tcllib, but for a single-column table of IP addresses there's no need for any complexity.